# Careers - filter by location & tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs

On Careers I thought it wold be nice to be able to filter by [tag](/questions/tagged/tag), possibly multiple, in additional to location.  Nothing fancy, but something like ....

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OytUi.jpg]

The image of tags is stolen from the SO side to convey the idea. I suspect functionality on the Careers side would need to be a bit different.  Recent tags would likely make sense.  Favorite tags, particularly the more specific ones might not (e.g., a job posting for [entity-framework-4.1](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-4.1), [mod-perl2](/questions/tagged/mod-perl2)).

Anyway, the image is just to give a sense of the idea.

Comment: That’s a nice idea. On Careers, however, we don’t make a strong distinction between tags and regular search terms – in both cases we do a full-text search. (We aren’t as robust as the main SO sites in that regard.)

What you show there is a nice way of exposing the current count of jobs by tag, and it’s a UI that will be familiar to SO users. Let’s see what others have to say.

Comment: I noticed that clicking on a tag enters a quoted "search term".  I don't think the site needs to do much more than it does, I was viewing it more like a typing shortcut.  `NY + SQL`, or whatever.

Comment: @Matt while this request didn't get much attention, this is something nice to have... any plans to do it?